# How to get validation correct according to Radio Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form = $("#Form-3");
    var FName = $("#fname"); //Creates Variables for elements in form
    var Tele = $("#tele"); 
    var Address = $("#address");
    var Email = $("#email");
    var Credit = $("#Card")
    var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9.]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/; //ragex code- used to validate email 
    

    
    FName.blur(validateFName);  //blur is a method which attaches a functiom to run when an event occurs
    Email.blur(validateEmail); 
    Tele.blur(validateTele);
    Address.blur(validateAddress);
    Credit.blur(validateCard);
 

    form.submit (function(){
        
        if (validateFName() & validateTele() & validateEmail() & validateAddress() & validateCard()){ //If it passes all of these then return true 
            
        return true;    
    }
        else  {
                return false;        
              }

       
        });
        function validateCard(){    //Validates Credit Card 
      var Visa = /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/;                //Ragex code for Credit Cards 
      var MasterCard = /^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{14})$/; 
      var CC = Credit.val();
       
    $("#Visa").click(function() {             //Tick Radio Button
    $("#Card").show(); 
      if (Visa.test(CC) ){   // If user input is equal to both Visa Or Mastercard Then Valid 
        document.getElementById("CardError").textContent ="";
        return true;
       }
    }); 
        
    $("#Master").click(function() {       //Checks MasterCard button. 
    $("#Card").show();
     if(MasterCard.test(CC)){
        document.getElementById("CardError").textContent =""; //Display Error
         return true;
    } 
     else {
        document.getElementById("CardError").textContent ="Please Ensure Card Detail Is Correct"; //Display Error
        return false;
    }
});
}

});
  
    <label for="Card">Credit Card (16 Digit Number)</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="Visa" name="Type1">
    <label>Visa</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="Master" name="Type1">
    <label>MasterCard</label>
    <input id="Card" name="Card" type="text" hidden="true" />
    <label id="CardError"></label>
```

In here I have two radio Buttons one for Visa Card and the other for MasterCard I want it that when user clicks on visa radio button only visa validation works and not Mastercard number vice versa, right now nothing is happening, however I can it get it to when the user clicks on Visa or Mastercard both validation apply i.e. Visa validation works when Mastercard radio buton is chosen. How can I specifically set it to one form of validation?

Comment: Can you answer the following, please? What are you doing? What do you want it to happen? What is happening now?

Comment: Nothing is happening at the moment but when  go on console its error says: Validation2.js:126 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

Comment: Isn't this error message clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the JavaScript. Change this part of the script:

```
    }
});
else {
    document.getElementById("CardError").textContent ="Please Ensure Card Detail Is Correct"; //Display Error
    return false;
}
```

To this:

```
    } else {
        document.getElementById("CardError").textContent ="Please Ensure Card Detail Is Correct"; //Display Error
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
function validateCard() { //Validates Credit Card 
  var Visa = /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/; //Ragex code for Credit Cards 
  var MasterCard = /^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{14})$/;
  var CC = Credit.val();

  $("#Visa").click(function() { //Tick Radio Button
    $("#Card").prop("hidden", false).removeAttr("hidden");
    console.log("Hi");
    if (Visa.test(CC)) { // If user input is equal to both Visa Or Mastercard Then Valid 
      document.getElementById("CardError").textContent = "";
      return true;
    }
  });
  $("#Master").click(function() { //Checks MasterCard button. 
    $("#Card").show();
    if (MasterCard.test(CC)) {
      $("#CardError").text(); //Display Error
      return true;
    } else {
      $("#CardError").text("Please Ensure Card Detail Is Correct"); //Display Error
      return false;
    }
  });
}

validateCard();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<label for="Card">Credit Card (16 Digit Number)</label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" id="Visa" name="Type1">
<label>Visa</label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" id="Master" name="Type1">
<label>MasterCard</label>
<input id="Card" name="Card" type="text" hidden="true" />
<label id="CardError"></label>
```

Comment: Thanks I managed to get rid of the errors but now the text box doesnt appear when the radio button is clicked.

Comment: @elmashrafi Can you create a jsBin or something similar so that we can play around it?

Comment: i.e. Textbox to enter card detail should appear after selecting a radio button

Comment: @elmashrafi Okay, create a fiddle first. `:)`

Comment: @elmashrafi Have a look at my answer, please? `:)`

Comment: Yes thats what i does currebtly but I want the textbox to appear after selecting a radio button so user can inout card detail.

Comment: Thanks but it just freezes and the box appears after I click submit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96473/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-el-mashrafi).

Comment: Your question screwed up the page! `:P`